# After "Maven->Update project",the configuration of source folder in build path has been changed

Tags: maven, buildpath

Here is the configuration before maven update project.

[image]

And this is the configuration after maven update project.

[image]

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>docx4j</name>

    <description>
        docx4j is a library which helps you to work with the Office Open
        XML file format as used in docx
        documents, pptx presentations, and xlsx spreadsheets.
    </description>
    <url>http://www.docx4java.org/</url>
    <licenses>
      <license>
        <name>Apache 2</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
      </license>
    </licenses>
    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git|git@github.com:plutext/docx4j.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <inceptionYear>2007</inceptionYear>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
      </properties> 


    <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory><!--  for a clean jar, be sure to avoid mixing mvn and eclipse output -->
        <testOutputDirectory>bin-testOutput</testOutputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resourcaes-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
            </plugin>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/pptx4j/java</source>
                                <source>src/xlsx4j/java</source>
                                <source>src/glox4j/java</source>
                                <source>src/diffx</source>
                                <!-- <source>src/xslfo</source> -->
                                <!-- <source>src/svg</source> -->
                                <!--source>src/sun</source -->
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- The Surefire Plugin is used during the test phase of the build lifecycle
                    to execute the unit tests of an application -->
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/samples/*.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/AbstractNumberingTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <!--  the below are prob not necessary, now that we are building from bin-mvn, and so avoiding stuff Eclipse puts into bin dir -->
                        <exclude>**/*.docx</exclude><!-- docx files in /src/test/resources add unwanted 1 MB to jar. -->
                        <exclude>src/test/resources/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>src/main/resources/README.txt</exclude><!--  sample log4j.xml and docx4j.properties are now in src/samples/_resources-->
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- The Source Plugin creates a jar archive of the source files of the
                    current project. -->
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- maven-javadoc-plugin seems to require large -Xmx so comment this
                out if your build is failing because you don't have enough. -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <maxmemory>512m</maxmemory>
                    <!-- 18 MB without the exclusion; still 15MB with -->
                    <!-- <excludePackageNames>org.plutext.jaxb.svg11:org.plutext.jaxb.xslfo</excludePackageNames> -->
                    <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam> <!-- for Java 8 -->
                 </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-echo</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy-echo</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>echo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <echos>
                        <echo>+-------------------------------------------------------+</echo>
                        <echo>!       Join the docx4j developers mailing list by      !</echo>
                        <echo>!       emailing docx4j-dev-subscribe@docx4java.org     !</echo>
                        <echo>+-------------------------------------------------------+</echo>
                    </echos>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!--  mvn versions:display-dependency-updates -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin> 

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.3,2.0)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <!-- be sure to get xml,xlst resources in various src trees -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xslt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/pptx4j/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xslt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/xlsx4j/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xslt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xslt</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>         
        </resources>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <id>standard-javadoc</id>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <description>
                                docx4j Open XML manipulation library
                            </description>
                            <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                            <locale>en_AU</locale>
                            <name>Javadoc report</name>
                            <quiet>true</quiet>
                            <serialwarn>false</serialwarn>
                            <show>private</show>
                            <source>1.6</source>
                            <stylesheet>maven</stylesheet>
                            <version>true</version>
                        </configuration>
                        <reports>
                            <report>javadoc</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.plutext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-svg11</artifactId><!-- previously part of docx4j source -->
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--  events -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.engio</groupId>
            <artifactId>mbassador</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  From 3.0, docx4j uses slf4j --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  instead of FOP's commons-logging -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>       

        <!--  .. default to log4j implementation, just like docx4j 2.8.1 and earlier.
                 UNLESS creating shaded jar for Android.  --> 
         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>  <!-- ns prefix mapper uses org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrTokenizer -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <!--  required for ole introspection -->
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version> <!--  2.2 works -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- you can comment out if you don't want
             to use Plutext's commercial PDF Converter. 
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>        
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>       


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>        
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



    <!-- these two are to correct issues in fop dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.arnx</groupId>
    <artifactId>wmf2svg</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.8</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jaxb-namespaceprefixmapper-interfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>JAXBNamespacePrefixMapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <!-- http://dev.plutext.org/forums/docx-java-f6/dependency-management-improvements-t739.html -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  since 3.1.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!--  for anon functionality; since 3.3.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thedeanda</groupId>
            <artifactId>lorem</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
            <version>3.1.0</version>  
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hankcs</groupId>
            <artifactId>hanlp</artifactId>
            <version>portable-1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>

    <profiles> <!--  use -P eg mvn -Psign-artifacts  -->
        <profile>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>



        <profile>
            <id>github-mvn-repo</id>
            <build>

                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <altDeploymentRepository>internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</altDeploymentRepository>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                        <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.12</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <server>github</server>
                            <merge>true</merge>
                            <message>Maven artifacts for ${project.version}</message>  <!-- git commit message -->
                            <noJekyll>true</noJekyll>                                  <!-- disable webpage processing -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</outputDirectory> <!-- matches distribution management repository url above -->
                            <branch>refs/heads/mvn-repo</branch>                        <!-- remote branch name -->
                            <includes><include>**/*</include></includes>
                            <repositoryName>docx4j</repositoryName>      <!-- github repo name -->
                            <repositoryOwner>plutext</repositoryOwner>    <!-- github username  -->
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                          <!-- run site-maven-plugin's 'site' target as part of the build's normal 'deploy' phase -->
                          <execution>
                            <goals>
                              <goal>site</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                          </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>           
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

I didn't find where to configure the "excluded" of sourcefolder in pom.xml

Comment: The source folder `src/pptx4j/java` is added by build-helper-maven-plugin via goal `add-source`.

Comment: @Mincong Huang thanks for ur reply.But in Project Explorer in eclipse,the icon of `src/pptx4j/java` is a folder,instead of a package.And in build path the `excluded` of src/pptx4j/java is `**`,so i think all files in `src/pptx4j/java` have been filtered.